# Passing regular expression as parameter

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I am trying to pass a regular expression as a parameter. What should I fix in my code?
My goal is to send `find` and the regular expression string, then use `grep` on the parameter so I can do whatever I want with what `grep` finds (which is print the count of occurrences).

This is what I send:

```
$ ./lab12.sh find [Gg]reen
```

Here's my bash code:

```
if [[ "$1" == "find" ]]
then
    declare -i cnt=0
    for file in /tmp/beatles/*.txt ; do
        if [[ grep -e $2 ]]  //problem is here...
        then
            ((cnt=cnt+1))
        fi
    done
    echo "$cnt songs contain the pattern "$2""
fi
```

Comment: Square brackets are part of glob syntax (wildcards)

Comment: It would produce undesirable results (pathname expansion would happen) if you have any files starting with `G` or `g` in your current directory. If not it would go unmodified as `[Gg]reen`. To produce desirable results, single quote the whole string

Comment: Also, unmatched patterns being treated literally is only the *default* behavior of `bash`. You can configure it to raise an error (`shopt -s failglob`) or disappear (`shopt -s nullglob`) as well.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/.  It is a shell script validator and will also find practices that may cause your problems.  See also https://wizardzines.com/comics/shellcheck/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement takes a command. `[[` being one, and `grep` is another, writing `[[ grep ... ]]` is essentially as wrong as writing `vim grep`, or `cat grep` etc, just use:

```
if grep -q -e "$pattern"
then
  ...
```

instead.

The `-q` switch to grep will disable output, but set the exit status to 0 (success) when the pattern is matches, and 1 (failure) otherwise, and the if statement will only execute the then block if the command succeded.

Using `-q` will allow grep to exit as soon as the first line is matches.

And as always, remember to wrap your paremeter expansions in double quotes, to avoid [pathname expansion and wordsplitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Note that square brackets `[...]` will be interpreted by your calling shell, and you should escape them, or wrap the whole pattern in quotes.

It's always recommended use single quotes, as the only special character is another single quote.

```
$ ./lab12.sh find '[Gg]reen'
```

Comment: Not just "can"; it *will* be interpreted. The question is whether the pattern produces any matches.

Comment: @chepner I guess it depends on what shell calls the program, and how it's configured. For all practical matter you are correct.